# Scoped directory access API throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I'm currently trying to add Android N support to my app. I'm using the new [Scoped Directory Access API](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/scoped-folder-access.html) to read my app's storage directory on external storage, like so:

```
public void requestExternalStoragePermissions(int requestCode) {
    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    StorageVolume volume = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
    Intent intent = volume.createAccessIntent("MyApp");
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

However, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on `startActivityForResult`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1635)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4858)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4844)
    at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:7125)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1150)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1139)
    ....
```

What am I doing wrong?

These files must be easily accessible to the user in a file manager, so `getExternalFilesDir()` is **NOT** an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the new Scoped Directory Access API only supports the standard media directories (`Documents`, `Music`, `Pictures`, etc).

From the [API reference for `StorageVolume.createAccessIntent(String directoryName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)):

`directoryName`: must be one of `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_PODCASTS`, `DIRECTORY_RINGTONES`, `DIRECTORY_ALARMS`, `DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS`, `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, `DIRECTORY_MOVIES`, `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, `DIRECTORY_DCIM`, or `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`, or `null` to request access to the entire volume.

Comment: Is it possible to figure out when the user has denied permission using "Don't Ask Again"?